Is it possible for a complex function to be differentiable everywhere but have a discontinuous derivative?
Theorem: $f(z)$ is holomorphic if its real part and imaginary part $u$, $v$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation.
The continuity of the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ is used to prove $u_{yx}=u_{xy}=v_{yy}$ and $v_{yx}=v_{xy}=-u_{yy}$ so that $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$ also satisfies the given conditions and is further differentiable. However, I don't know how to construct a counterexample where the partial derivatives of  $u$ and $v$ are discontinuous.

I too don't know if such a case is possible. What  methods have you tried till now to find counter-examples?

I considered expressing $f$ as $f(r,\theta)$ and solving $f_\theta-irf_r=0$. By a change of variables, I obtain $\theta=s+C_1(t)$ and $r=C_2(t)e^{-is}$. To make $f$ differentiable most of the time but discontinuous when $r=0$, my idea is to let the Jacobian determinant of the variable substitution be $0$ at $r=0$. This indeed produces some solutions, such as $f(z)=\sqrt z$. However, these examples do not satisfy the periodicity of $f$ with respect to $\theta$.

Ok, I will work on this method. A beautiful one indeed...

Actually, I don't think it's worth spending time on this method. It seems that this approach shows nothing more than that 'if $f$ is differentiable in a region, then it is a function of $re^{i\theta}$ in that region.'...

There are no counter-examples, this is what the Looman–Menchoff theorem proves. See references in the duplicate link.

The title here does not match the actual question.
